# Can i Install Ubuntu on Surface 3 (Atom based W8.1 Tablet - NOT the pro 3)

Tags: system-installation

After the horribleness that Microsoft is intent to push onto it's users with W10, I'm keen to GTFO of their ecosystem once and for all. Hence id like to put a flavor of Linux onto my Surface 3 (NOT SURFACE PRO3!). My past experience with Ubuntu has been good so I'm keen to see if it will run on the Surface 3. I followed a few steps to get a live USB stick up and running, but it doesn't want to boot to anything but a black screen.

Does anybody know of a guide regarding how to get Ubuntu running on the Surface 3?

I'm fed up of Microsoft and I really don't want to be tied to them anymore, but I'm loath to sell my Surface 3 cause it really is a nifty wee machine! Help is greatly appreciated.

(The device is an Atom based X86/64 machine, and there is support for other OS via Bios tweaks)